# Cast function expression tree from object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I've ended up with a situation where an *function expression tree* `Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>>` is assigned to a global variable of type *object* and then later in the code I need to call a different method with the expression. I can't change the global objects type; it has to be object.

The code won't compile when trying to call the second method with the global object unless I cast the object as `Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>>`. The problem is I don't know what *TProperty* is at the point that the second method is called.

I've created a quick demo app to illustrate the point (c# console app written in VS2010) - the real application looks nothing like this.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace FuncExpressionTree
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public string StringProperty { get; set; }
        public int IntProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class Helper<T>
        where T : ViewModel
    {
        private object _global;

        public void Execute()
        {
            AssignToGlobal((T vm) => vm.StringProperty);

            ProcessGlobal();

            AssignToGlobal((T vm) => vm.IntProperty);

            ProcessGlobal();
        }

        public void AssignToGlobal<TClass, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            _global = expression;
        }

        public void ProcessGlobal()
        {
            // invalid cast exception thrown when IntProperty is assigned to _global
            AssignToGlobal((Expression<Func<T, string>>)_global);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            (new Helper<ViewModel>()).Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

If we focus on the `Execute()` method.

1. First *global* is assigned expression for the string property.
2. ProcessGlobal executes and works because I'm casting to `Expression<Func<T, string>>`.
3. Next *global* is assigned expression for int property.
4. ProcessGlobal again executes but its at this point that an invalid cast exception is thrown. It would work if I changed it to cast `Expression<Func<T, int>>` instead but then the string property wouldn't work. Also `Expression<Func<T, object>>` throws an invalid cast exception.

I feel like Im missing something and that it should be possible to do something with the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace to dynamically invoke the the second method (eg AssignToGlobal within ProcessGlobal in the above example).

So how can I get this to work in a generic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public void ProcessGlobal()
    {
        var globalType = _global.GetType(); // globalType = Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>>
        var functionType = globalType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // functionType = Func<TClass, TProperty>
        var functionGenericArguments = functionType.GetGenericArguments(); // v = [TClass, TProperty]
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("AssignToGlobal").MakeGenericMethod(functionGenericArguments); //functionGenericArguments = AssignToGlobal<TClass, TProperty>
        method.Invoke(this, new[] { this._global }); // Call AssignToGlobal<TClass, TProperty>)(this._global);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me although I needed to tweak it to invoke with 2 arguments ie the TClass instance and global.